# fetching html source from webkit in Ios apps

Tags: ios, iphone

webkit is used and javascript is enabled by default.

The entire content is not fetched. only partial content is fetched. what needs to be done any suggestion.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.htmlView.navigationDelegate = self;
   [self fetchHtmlContent];
}
- (void)fetchHtmlContent {
   NSURL *TheUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@“https://www.101cookbooks.com/archives/blueberry-beet-pancakes-vegan-recipe.html“];
   [self.htmlView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:TheUrl]];
}


- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView
didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {

   [webView evaluateJavaScript:@“document.body.outerHTML” completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
       if (error == nil)
       {
           if (result != nil)
           {
               NSLog(@“result: %@“, result);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           NSLog(@“evaluateJavaScript error : %@“, error.localizedDescription);
       }
   }];
}
```

There is a js code in the link mentioned in code which will be executed so only then source code has to be fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was using emulator to run the above code where js code doesn't seem to execute..
Tested on phone worked...